# Calculus chain rule question?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I figure out the following

$f(x)=(x^2-9)^2$

determine the values for which $f'(x)<0$

I know the derivative is using the chain rule is $2(x^2-9)(2x)$ but how would I figure out the rest.

Comment: $f'(x)$ is not $2(x-9)(2x)$. It is $2(x^2-9)(2x)$.

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: Now the you have the correct equation, can you proceed? It sometimes helps to look at a [*plot*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B2%28x%5E2%E2%88%929%29%282x%29+%3C+0%5D) to validate your analysis. Regards

Comment: @amzoti It seems  that f(x)<0 is for all real numbers less than zero?

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: Compare Ross M's nice answer with the plot and what do you get? Regards

Answer (score 2):

Expand your derivative to $4x(x-3)(x+3) \lt 0$.  It will change sign at $-3, 0 , +3.$  Since the inequality is true when $x$ is very large and negative, the solution is $x \in (-\infty,-3) \cup (0,3)$

Comment: yes I like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you usually do in precalculus, analyzing where a polynomial is negative/positive given its roots.

$4x(x^2-9) < 0 \iff x(x-3)(x+3) < 0.$ Then you analyze $x$ between the zeros.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=(x^2-9)^2$
$$f'(x)=2(x^2-9)2x=4x(x-3)(x+3)<0\Rightarrow x\in(-\infty,-3)\cup (0,3)$$

Comment: you are wellcome

Answer (score 1):

Solve the inequality $f'(x)<0$.  That is, $$f'(x)=4x(x^2-9)=4x^3-36x<0\implies 4x^3<36x\implies x^3<9x$$  For $x>0$, the final inequality above becomes $$x^2<9\implies x\in(-3,3)$$ so that $x\in(0,3)$.  For $x<0$, the same inequality becomes $$x^2>9\implies x\in (-\infty, -3)\cup (3, \infty)$$ so that $x\in(-\infty, -3)$.  For $x=0$, the inequality is clearly not satisfied.

So the final solution is $$x\in(-\infty, -3)\cup(0,3).$$